# I need a way to populate data between date stamp in R

Tags: r, excel, database, r-markdown

I want to solve this in R. I have an excel file that records all population figure of >300 camps with a date stamp. The excel file looks like this.

[image]

The excel file only tracks when the population changes. what i want to do is populate/create population data between date stamp (the populated data would take the data from the last date stamp)

```
**SiteID    -   Date     -   Household** 

BTH001  - *01/01/2020*   - ***150*** 

BTH001  - *01/24/2020*  -  ***240***

BTH001  - *03/05/2020*   - ***80***
```

What i need is like this

```
**SiteID -  Date    -     Household** 

BTH001  - *01/01/2020*   - ***150***

(populated data) from **01/02/2020** to **01/23/2020**

BTH001  - *01/24/2020*    - ***240***

(populated data) from **01/24/2020** to **03/04/2020**

BTH001  -*03/05/2020*    -***80***
```

I have already loaded and cleaned the data in R and basically i want to populate those data for all 300 camps and i have no idea where to start in R but I know some basic R and i use R markdown to create dashboards and maps.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table`-approach of your question.

I broke things down, and added some comments, to let you see all steps.

**packages needed**

```
library( data.table )
library( zoo ) #for na.locf
```

**sample data**

```
#load sample data
DT <- data.table::fread("SiteID  Date  Household
BTH001  01/01/2020  150
BTH001  01/24/2020  240
BTH001  03/05/2020  80")
#    SiteID       Date Household
# 1: BTH001 01/01/2020       150
# 2: BTH001 01/24/2020       240
# 3: BTH001 03/05/2020        80
```

**code**

```
#now, set the Date-column as a real data
DT[, Date := as.Date( Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y" ) ]
#DT looks like this now ...
### > str(DT)
### Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
### $ SiteID   : chr  "BTH001" "BTH001" "BTH001"
### $ Date     : Date, format: "2020-01-01" "2020-01-24" "2020-03-05"
### $ Household: int  150 240 80

#now, create a new data.table, with a Date column from the minimum Date to the maximum date of DT
DT.complete <- data.table( Date = seq( min(DT$Date, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                       max(DT$Date, na.rm = TRUE),
                                       by = "1 days" ) )
#now, join the data from DT to DT.complete
DT.complete[ DT, 
             `:=`( SiteID = i.SiteID, Household = i.Household ),
             on = .( Date ) ]
#finally fill in the NA's
cols <- c("SiteID", "Household" ) #colnames to be filled
#fill NA's inside cols with locf..
DT.complete[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, zoo::na.locf ), .SDcols = cols ]
```

**output**

```
#final output
#           Date SiteID Household
#  1: 2020-01-01 BTH001       150
#  2: 2020-01-02 BTH001       150
#  3: 2020-01-03 BTH001       150
#  4: 2020-01-04 BTH001       150
#  5: 2020-01-05 BTH001       150
#  6: 2020-01-06 BTH001       150
#  7: 2020-01-07 BTH001       150
#  8: 2020-01-08 BTH001       150
#  9: 2020-01-09 BTH001       150
# 10: 2020-01-10 BTH001       150
# 11: 2020-01-11 BTH001       150
# 12: 2020-01-12 BTH001       150
# 13: 2020-01-13 BTH001       150
# 14: 2020-01-14 BTH001       150
# 15: 2020-01-15 BTH001       150
# 16: 2020-01-16 BTH001       150
# 17: 2020-01-17 BTH001       150
# 18: 2020-01-18 BTH001       150
# 19: 2020-01-19 BTH001       150
# 20: 2020-01-20 BTH001       150
# 21: 2020-01-21 BTH001       150
# 22: 2020-01-22 BTH001       150
# 23: 2020-01-23 BTH001       150
# 24: 2020-01-24 BTH001       240
# 25: 2020-01-25 BTH001       240
# 26: 2020-01-26 BTH001       240
# 27: 2020-01-27 BTH001       240
# 28: 2020-01-28 BTH001       240
# 29: 2020-01-29 BTH001       240
# 30: 2020-01-30 BTH001       240
# 31: 2020-01-31 BTH001       240
# 32: 2020-02-01 BTH001       240
# 33: 2020-02-02 BTH001       240
# 34: 2020-02-03 BTH001       240
# 35: 2020-02-04 BTH001       240
# 36: 2020-02-05 BTH001       240
# 37: 2020-02-06 BTH001       240
# 38: 2020-02-07 BTH001       240
# 39: 2020-02-08 BTH001       240
# 40: 2020-02-09 BTH001       240
# 41: 2020-02-10 BTH001       240
# 42: 2020-02-11 BTH001       240
# 43: 2020-02-12 BTH001       240
# 44: 2020-02-13 BTH001       240
# 45: 2020-02-14 BTH001       240
# 46: 2020-02-15 BTH001       240
# 47: 2020-02-16 BTH001       240
# 48: 2020-02-17 BTH001       240
# 49: 2020-02-18 BTH001       240
# 50: 2020-02-19 BTH001       240
# 51: 2020-02-20 BTH001       240
# 52: 2020-02-21 BTH001       240
# 53: 2020-02-22 BTH001       240
# 54: 2020-02-23 BTH001       240
# 55: 2020-02-24 BTH001       240
# 56: 2020-02-25 BTH001       240
# 57: 2020-02-26 BTH001       240
# 58: 2020-02-27 BTH001       240
# 59: 2020-02-28 BTH001       240
# 60: 2020-02-29 BTH001       240
# 61: 2020-03-01 BTH001       240
# 62: 2020-03-02 BTH001       240
# 63: 2020-03-03 BTH001       240
# 64: 2020-03-04 BTH001       240
# 65: 2020-03-05 BTH001        80
#           Date SiteID Household
```